# Dropbox API Chooser with JS from localhost: Origin does not match any app domain

Tags: javascript, dropbox-api

I try to get access to my dropbox app from localhost to download images from there. The popup for the chooser appears, but I get an error:

*Origin does not match any app domain*

**SCRIPT**

```
 <div id="container"><a id="link"></a></div>


<script>
  var button = Dropbox.createChooseButton({
    success: function (files) {
      var linkTag = document.getElementById('link');
      linkTag.href = files[0].link;
      linkTag.textContent = files[0].link;
    },
    linkType: 'direct'
  });
  document.getElementById('container').appendChild(button);
</script>
```

I have included the dropins.js with the app-key, generated on dropbox.

**Settings Dropbox**

OAUTH2 Redirect URI is set to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8020/
```

Any ideas? I´ve still tried a lot:

- URI without Port
- URI with my folder .../balin-spice/
- URI localhost in connection with a URI shortener

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There should be a section in the App console (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps/info/...) called "Drop-ins domains." Make sure to add all the domains you're going to use there. (It looks like you probably need to add `127.0.0.1` and/or `localhost`.)

Comment: Yeah, great I´ve forgotten to add the Drop-Ins domain! Thank you smarx